# process json returned from coldfusion cfc

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, cfc

Hi I have a form select bound to a cfc - i can see the json returned but its not displaying on my form - i have the code as below hope someone can help:

FORM

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#CountriesList").change(function()
{
if($(this).val() != '')
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mycfc.cfc?method=GetCities&returnformat=json",
data: ({
CountryID: $(this).val()
}),
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml)
{
$('#Cities option').remove();
$(xml).find('record').each(function()
{
$("#Cities").append('<option value="' + $(this).find('tape_width').text() + '">' + $(this).find('tape_width').text() + '<\/option>');
});
}
});
}
});

})

// -->
</script>

<cfsilent>
<cfinvoke component="mycfc" method="CountriesList" returnvariable="CountriesList"/>
</cfsilent>
 <cfoutput>
 <label for="CountriesList">Select Country:</label>
 <select name="CountriesList" id="CountriesList">
<option value="" selected="selected">...</option>
 <cfloop query="CountriesList"><option value="#BAND#">#CountriesList.BAND#</option></cfloop>
</select>
<label for="Cities">Select City:</label>
<select name="cities" id="Cities"><option value="">...</option></select>
</cfoutput>
```

The actual CFC is as below:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction access="remote" name="CountriesList" output="false" returntype="query">
<cfquery name="SelectAllCountries" datasource="test">
 SELECT DISTINCT BAND
 FROM FABRICS
 WHERE TYPE='venetian'
 AND isACTIVE='true'
 ORDER BY BAND
</cfquery>
<cfreturn SelectAllCountries>
</cffunction>
<cffunction access="remote" name="GetCities" output="false" returntype="query">
<cfargument name="CountryID" required="yes" type="any" default="" />
<cfquery name="Cities" datasource="test">
 SELECT TAPE_WIDTH
 FROM tapes
 WHERE SLAT_WIDTH='#arguments.CountryID#'
</cfquery>
<cfreturn Cities>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Could someone point out where am going wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question, please?  I'm not sure if you didn't include the form or if it got eaten by the fact that you didn't format it properly as code.

Comment: looks like it, i will try and edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a similar problem I was jhaving by adding queryformat as follows:

```
$.getJSON("getContacts.cfc?method=getContacts&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column
```

prior to this I was seeing the json being returned (through firebug) but it was not dipslaying...

Hope it helps

Comment: How did you get on - any luck?

Comment: Hi Simon,No lock yet...I have the following code:<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#contentdiv').html('&& nbsp;');
 $("#idm").change( function() {
 var formval = { idm:$(this) .val()};
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   cfc: "request.cfm",
   dataType: "json",
   data: formval,
   success: function(response){
   $('#contentdiv').fadeIn(2000).append(response.userID);
   }
  });  
 });   
 });
</script>   So am calling the cfc from a cfm page

Comment: Finally got it...didnt notice i was returning the wrong var...thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning json, why are you specifying an XML datatype? Try

```
datatype: 'json'
```